# Ruby on Rails difficult query

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I need to create difficult query, but I don't understand, how to do that in more efficient way.

The situation is following:

```
class Owner
  has_many: A
end

class A
  has_many: C
end

# category: string
class B
  has_many: C
end

# flag: boolean
class C
  belongs_to: A
  belongs_to: B

  scope :filtered, -> { where(b: { category: 'smth' }) }
end
```

I need to get all A records which belongs to specific owner except for those who:

```
a.c.filtered.last.flag == true
```

a.c.filtered can be empty, a.c can be empty and in this case I don't need to exclude such A records.

Of course, I can do it in for loop, but I have too many records and I believe it's not an efficient way.

Comment: Its very unclear what you actually are looking to get out of the query. Can you improve the example with models that actually work, add an example of the data and the output you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work?

```
A.where(c: C.filtered.where(flag: true))
```